# How does PCA work when we reduce the original space to 2 or higher-dimensional space?

Tags: math, optimization, linear-algebra, principal-component-analysis

How does PCA work when we reduce the original space to a 2 or higher-dimensional space? I understand the case when we reduce the dimensionality to $1$, but not this case.

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & \mathrm{Tr}\left( \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{w} \right)\\ \text{subject to} & \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{w} = 1\end{array}$$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3736092

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at the wikipedia article of [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis#Further_components), where it says:

*"The $k$th component can be found by subtracting the first $k − 1$ principal components from $\mathbf{X}$:"*

$$\hat{\mathbf{X}}_k = \mathbf{X} - \sum_{s=1}^{k-1}\mathbf{X}\mathbf{w}_s\mathbf{w}_s^T$$

Then you repeat the process to find the next component:

$$\mathbf{w}_k = \arg\max \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{\hat{X}}^T_k\mathbf{\hat{X}}_k\mathbf{w}$$
$$\text{s.t. } \mathbf{w}_k^T\mathbf{w}_k = 1$$

Answer (score 0):

You can also understand the logic from the view of constrained optimisation.
Introduce a Lagrange function:
$$
\mathcal{L} = \text{Tr} (w^{T} X X^{T} w) - \lambda w^{T} w
$$
And take the derivative with respect to $w$:
$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial w} = 2 (X X^{T} - \lambda) w
$$
For the general case of dimension $\geqslant 1$ $w$ is a set of vectors $w = (w_1 w_2 \ldots w_n)$.
This expression vanishes, if for some index $i$ $w_i$ is an of eigenvector of $XX^{T}$ with the eigenvalue $\lambda_i$, and all other components are set to zero. In other words, stationary points are the eigenvectors of $X X^{T}$.

The condititon $w^T w = 1$ imposes the orthogonality condition on the eigenvectors. In fact, going back to the initial functional, one sees, that $w_i X X^{T} w_j = \lambda_j w_i^{T} w_j = 0$ for $i \neq j$. Therefore, we have finally:
$$
\mathcal{L} =\sum \lambda_i - \lambda
$$
Which is maximized for any $k \geq 1$, by taking $k$ largest eigenvalues.

Comment: 1.) Is the duality gap zero for such functions? 2.) The $L$ is minimised for k largest Eigen values. And the major concern I haven't seen this type of formulation without building the dual problem, can you link a resource? (Not doubting, but I am interested)